# CSS not read in Android 4.4 WebView

Tags: android, css, android-webview, chromium

I'm using a WebView in my app. This loads html, css and js files on the device. Everything works fine for API18 or lower. In 19, Chromium is used for the WebView and my app no longer works. There's no CSS applied to the html. The targetSdk is 18. Upgrading targetSdk to 19 causes my Javascript to malfuntion...

Does any body know what could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

> There's no CSS applied to the html.

In 99% of cases it means CSS is not loaded.

> Upgrading targetSdk to 19 causes my Javascript to malfuntion...

Errors? Can you post errors here?